# Referencing Silverlight Toolkit for WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, toolkit

I am developing a 7.1 App for the Windows Phone device. I downloaded the latest silverlight toolkit, which is version 5.

However, when I try to add a reference to my Solution (In this case the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`) I get following error:

```
A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project
```

My XAML header goes like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="JOKR_Pivot.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"

                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JOKR_Pivot"
                            xmlns:tilteffect="clr-namespace:JOKR_Pivot"
                            local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the wrong toolkit.

This is what you are looking for: [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888)

Comment: WP7 is based on silverlight 4. In your question you mentioned you downloaded silverlight 5 version. Also the error message suggests it.